# Javascript - Calculating percentage difference from the index before it

Tags: javascript, math

I have an array `stateArr` that I am trying to calculate the percentage growth based on the number in front of it.

For example, `index[0] - index[1] / index[0] * 100` followed by `index[1] - index[2] / index[1] * 100` and so on...  which would give me my % result. I have an array length of 23.

At the moment my outcome has been stuck on NaN. 
My issue is not knowing how to call to say subtract from the index before the one you are currently on. I've tried [i-1] which did not give me the desired results

Here is my code

```
 //removing of commas
    const percentage = []
        stateArr.stateArr.forEach(({ DataValue }) => {
            percentage.push(Number(DataValue.replace(/,/g, '')));
        });
```

---

```
console.log(percentage)
    return of console.log percentage 

(23) […]
​
0: 1378653.7
​
1: 1470393
​
2: 1582377.4
​
3: 1709938.7
​
4: 1702775.7
​
5: 1743650.6
​
6: 1825424
​
7: 1902318.8
​
8: 1990140.8
​
9: 2072177
​
10: 2103618.2
​
11: 2111138
​
12: 2026486.9
​
13: 2058137.9
​
14: 2091586
​
15: 2144497.3
​
16: 2220867.6
​
17: 2312540.1
​
18: 2428598.4
​
19: 2500950.4
​
20: 2610682.3
​
21: 2721651
​
22: 2792029.1
```

---

```
//new array without commas
const finalPercentage = percentage.map((stPer, i ) => {
        return 100 * Math.abs((stPer - stPer[i]) / ((stPer + stPer[i]) / 2))
    })

console.log(finalPercentage) 

returns NaN
```

Comment: The problem that you are having is `stPer` is the value of the current position in the array, and i is the position itself. So when you do `stPer[i]` you are trying to get the character in the position of `i` in the value and not of the array itself.

Comment: is there anything that I need to replace `stPer[i]` with in order to get my desired result? Doing the calculation with stPer - stPer would then bring my result to zero. My issue is understanding how to subtract by the index incremented array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More lit solution:

```
const percentageArr = myArr.map((v, i) => i === 0 ? 100 : Math.round(v * 100 / myArr[i - 1]))
```

Comment: Sorry, when trying this with my project I am not getting the expected results. I don't really understand what's going on in your solution. Do you mind giving a quick break down and I may be able to alter the solution to my need as I better understand what's going on

Comment: Sure, `map` function is looping through an existing array of numbers(myArr) and creates a new one. Here I'm saying if the index is 0(first element) return 100 otherwise calculate the growth in percentage from previous value and return that percentage. If you need the opposite, just reverse the array. `myArr.reverse()`

Comment: In this solution what does variable v represent? I've adjusted your solution to do a very basic addition between the first index (which I assume to be variable v) and the index before that which I believe is `[i -1]`. I changed the logic to `100 : v + [i - 1]) but return result is my index + 1. For example, 1000 is now 10001.

Comment: yes, `v` is the current value and `myArr[i -1]` is the previous one, not only `[i -1]`.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense, I did not include `myArr[i-1]` which was giving me some issues. with some adjustments, I was able to get the desired result. Thank you for the clarification